In Dead Like Me, why can't the dead girl speak to her mother when she visits her?
I just watched the first three episodes of the weirdest, quirkiest TV show ever, Dead Like Me.
A dead girl is forced to live among the living, but not reveal who she is. She looks different than when she was alive. Yes, the show is a little bit contrived.
She misses her family and goes to visit her mother. Exactly what I would have done, she reveals information that only she could know, to identify herself.
When she talks to identify herself to her mother, she can't make the words come out. Her mother doesn't believe her and chases her away. Later, when she's talking to her dead boss, he seems to imply that God prevents you from talking to your friends who are still alive by making you forget what to say.
Is that what happened?
Was that the horrible anguish that her boss predicted would happen if she visited her mom again?

It sounds like you've seen all the relevant episodes and need to write a self-answer

No, I saw an episode and I think I understand it but I wanted to make sure because I'm autistic and I don't understand what's going on in other people's minds and motivations. == Also, this would be the first reference to God in the show,  and also the first time he took direct action. Everything else has been done by his agents. == And if I understood it, I wouldn't answer the question; I wouldn't ask it in the first place. And why would people ask questions if they already knew the answer? I don't understand normal people, and that's why I asked the question.

You don't get a lot more than you've already seen. In a later episode she manages to speak to her mother in character as Millie but the whole 'you can't go to your relatives' is largely an unexplained plot device to stop George from doing precisely that.

OK, write that as an answer to get points and mark it as answered.

Does she ever talk to her sister again?
